# sidekiq-pro batches don't appear to release redis memory after batches complete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sidekiq

We are using sidekiq pro 1.7.3 and sidekiq 3.1.4, Ruby 2.0, Rails 4.0.5 on heroku with the redis green addon with 1.75G of memory.

We run a lot of sidekiq batch jobs, probably around 2 million jobs a day.  What we've noticed is that the redis memory steadily increases over the course of a week.  I would have expected that when the queues are empty and no workers are busy that redis would have low memory usage, but it appears to stay high.  I'm forced to do a flushdb pretty much every week or so because we approach our redis memory limit.

I've had a series of correspondence with Redisgreen and they suggested I reach out to the sidekiq community.  Here are some stats from redisgreen:

> Here's a quick summary of RAM use across your database:
>   The vast majority of keys in your database are simple values taking up 2 bytes each.
>   200MB is being consumed by "queue:low", the contents of your low-priority sidekiq queue.
>   The next largest key is "dead", which occupies about 14MB.

And:

> ```
> We just ran an analysis of your database - here is a summary of what we found in 23129 keys:
> 18448 strings with 1048468 bytes (79.76% of keys, avg size 56.83)
> 6 lists with 41642 items (00.03% of keys, avg size 6940.33)
> 4660 sets with 3325721 members (20.15% of keys, avg size 713.67)
> 8 hashs with 58 fields (00.03% of keys, avg size 7.25)
> 7 zsets with 1459 members (00.03% of keys, avg size 208.43)
> It appears that you have quite a lot of memory occupied by sets. For example - each of these sets have more than 10,000 members and occupies nearly 300KB:
> b-3819647d4385b54b-jids
> b-3b68a011a2bc55bf-jids
> b-5eaa0cd3a4e13d99-jids
> b-78604305f73e44ba-jids
> b-e823c15161b02bde-jids
> These look like Sidekiq Pro "batches". It seems like some of your batches are getting filled up with very large numbers of jobs, which is causing the additional memory usage that we've been seeing.
> Let me know if that sounds like it might be the issue.
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Don't be afraid to open a Sidekiq issue or email prosupport @ sidekiq.org directly.

Sidekiq Pro Batches have a default expiration of 3 days.  If you set the Batch's expires_in setting longer, the data will sit in Redis longer.  Unlike jobs, batches do not disappear from Redis once they are complete.  They need to expire over time.  This means you need enough memory in Redis to hold N days of Batches, usually not a problem for most people, but if you have a busy Sidekiq installation and are creating lots of batches, you might notice elevated memory usage.

Comment: Please note that Batches in Pro 2.0 will no longer require a tunable expiry and will be deleted as soon as they are no longer needed, meaning memory usage should go down significantly.  Pro 2.0 is due by March 2015.